# HTML (Forms stuck in nest)

Tags: html, forms

> I want to have four separate forms right under one another. However, when I enter the code below I get four nested forms. The first form nests the next three forms. The following form nests the next two forms, etc...

```
<form name="my form" method="get">
<div id="contactInfo">
<p><fieldset><legend><strong>Contact Info</legend></strong></p>
    <label>Name</label><input type="text" name="FullName" style="width: 300px;" value="First and last name" /> <br>
    <label>Street Address</label><input type="text" name="Address" style="width: 300px;"/> <br>
    <label>Zip Code</label><input type="text" name="ZipCode" /> <br>
    <label>Email</label><input type="text" name="EmailAddress"style="width: 300px;" value="address@example.com" /> <br>
    <label>Phone</label><input type="text" name="PhoneNumber" />

<p><fieldset><legend><strong>Best day(s) to schedule a visit</strong></legend></p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="date" id="date1" value="Mon" /> Monday
    <input type="checkbox" name="date" id="date2" value="Tues" /> Tuesday
    <input type="checkbox" name="date" id="date3" value="Wed" /> Wednesday
    <input type="checkbox" name="date" id="date4" value="Thur" /> Thursday
    <input type="checkbox" name="date" id="date5" value="Fri" /> Friday
    <input type="checkbox" name="date" id="date6" value="Sat" /> Saturday
    <input type="checkbox" name="date" id="date7" value="Sun" /> Sunday

<p><fieldset><legend><strong>Project Area</strong></legend></p>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice1" value="frontOfHouse" /> Front of House <br>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice2" value="Border" /> Border of Property <br>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice3" value="multipleAreas" /> Multiple Areas (please specify in Notes box below) <br>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice4" value="Other" /> Other (please specify in Notes box below) <br>

<p><fieldset><legend><strong>Additional Information</strong></legend></p>
Notes <br>
    <textarea name="comments" align="left" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>

<p></fieldset></p>

<input type="submit" value="Submit Request"/>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You've got one `</fieldset>` tag, but four `<fieldset>` tags. Make sure to close each one up, and you'll avoid the nesting issue!

Edit:

- A nesting issue shown in CodePen: http://codepen.io/cam5/pen/vXdGQz
- That pen, forked, with closing tags: http://codepen.io/cam5/pen/QKQNzw

Comment: Why the downvote? This is the correct answer. I'll go demonstrate with pens.

Comment: Thanks a lot Cameron. I didn't down vote though. I actually tried to upvote, but my reputation isn't high enough to vote yet. So even if I wanted to I couldn't downvote you. Thanks again for helping out with my rookie mistake

Comment: No worries, amigo. I'm sure it wasn't you who downvoted. Glad to have been able to help!

Answer (score -1):

Get the Fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/7p0g2hq9/

Be attentive with the tags.

```
<form name="my form" method="get">
<div id="contactInfo">
<fieldset><p><legend>
<strong>Contact Info</strong></legend>
</p>

<label>Name</label><input type="text" name="FullName" style="width: 300px;" value="First and last name" /> <br>
    <label>Street Address</label><input type="text" name="Address" style="width: 300px;"/> <br>
    <label>Zip Code</label><input type="text" name="ZipCode" /> <br>
    <label>Email</label><input type="text" name="EmailAddress"style="width: 300px;" value="address@example.com" /> <br>
    <label>Phone</label><input type="text" name="PhoneNumber" />

</fieldset>

<fieldset><p><legend><strong>Best day(s) to schedule a visit</strong></legend></p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="date" id="date1" value="Mon" /> Monday
    <input type="checkbox" name="date" id="date2" value="Tues" /> Tuesday
    <input type="checkbox" name="date" id="date3" value="Wed" /> Wednesday
    <input type="checkbox" name="date" id="date4" value="Thur" /> Thursday
    <input type="checkbox" name="date" id="date5" value="Fri" /> Friday
    <input type="checkbox" name="date" id="date6" value="Sat" /> Saturday
    <input type="checkbox" name="date" id="date7" value="Sun" /> Sunday
    </fieldset>
<fieldset><p><legend><strong>Project Area</strong></legend></p>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice1" value="frontOfHouse" /> Front of House <br>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice2" value="Border" /> Border of Property <br>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice3" value="multipleAreas" /> Multiple Areas (please specify in Notes box below) <br>
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice4" value="Other" /> Other (please specify in Notes box below) <br>
    </fieldset>
<fieldset><p><legend><strong>Additional Information</strong></legend></p>
Notes <br>
    <textarea name="comments" align="left" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>

</fieldset>

<input type="submit" value="Submit Request"/>
```

> If I helped, don't forget to mark as correct